# JPA Repository: JPQL Join Query

Tags: spring, jpa, jpql

So I have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Battle {

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "battle_sequence", sequenceName = "battle_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "battle_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private long id;
    private String title;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private BattleLevel difficulty;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Language language;
    private String prompt;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "battle", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Solution> solutions = new ArrayList<Solution>();
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "app_user_battle_id")
    private AppUser appUser;
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Solution {

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "solution_sequence", sequenceName = "solution_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "solution_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String solution;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "battle_solution_id")
    private Battle battle;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "app_user_solution_id")
    private AppUser appUser;
```

I am trying to write a custom join query to grab the battle based on the solutionId. Since the solution table holds the foreign key I will need to do a join to grab the details of battle. I am a bit confused at the syntax required to join these tables in my battle repository.

I'm expecting something like:
Optional (Battle) findBySolutionId(long solutionId);